# using Transaction query in jsp page

Tags: sql, jsp

I use below query in my jsp page. but I'm not sure Is it true to use this query in jsp page.

```
int i = st.executeUpdate("'BEGIN TRANSACTION DECLARE @id [int] SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() INSERT INTO  Viewer(Reserve_ID, F_Name, L_Name, Competition_ID, City, Phone, [E-mail]) VALUES (@id, '" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + 30 + "','" + city + "','" + phone + "','" + email + "' ) INSERT INTO  Reservation_Inf(Reservation_Date, Competition_ID, NumberOfTicket, Position_ID) VALUES ('" + dNow + "','" + 30 + "','" + 1 + "','" + 8 + "' ) COMMIT TRANSACTION '" );

if (i > 0) {
   response.sendRedirect("Success.jsp");
} else {
   response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
}
```

It gives this error :

```
 Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN TRANSACTION DECLARE @id [int] SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() INSERT INTO  Viewer(Reserve_ID, F_Name, L_Name, Competition_ID,'.
```